# Generating the input id with an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do you generate an input's `id` attribute, given a model? For example, if I have a model of `Person` with a `first_name` attribute, the form helper prints out a textbox with this html:

```
<input type="text" id="person_first_name" />
```

How can I generate that `person_first_name` from some other place in the code (like in a controller or some place)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following neutrino's advice and looked at the rails code a little bit more. I ended up pulling out a couple of private methods in the `InstanceTag` class and moving them around a little bit. I monkey patched this onto `ActiveRecord::Base`, which may not be the best solution, but it works right now:

```
def create_tag_id(method_name)
  object_name = ActionController::RecordIdentifier.singular_class_name(self)
  "#{sanitized_object_name(object_name)}_#{sanitized_method_name(method_name.to_s)}"
end

private
  def sanitized_object_name(object_name)
    object_name.gsub(/\]\[|[^-a-zA-Z0-9:.]/, "_").sub(/_$/, "")
  end

  def sanitized_method_name(method_name)
    method_name.sub(/\?$/,"")
  end
```

Comment: I did the same thing, but instead of putting those methods in the model I replaced and extended the form builder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819696/how-do-you-get-the-rails-generated-id-of-a-form-element-for-reference-in-javascri/5432558#5432558

Answer (score 1):

A good habit is to dig rails' code every now and then :)

These values are generated by private methods inside the nodoc-ed `InstanceTag` class. You can see the sources [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/InstanceTagMethods). Methods of interest are `add_default_name_and_id`, `tag_id`, and probably `tag_id_with_index`. Nothing fancy there.

Comment: Yeah, I did poke around InstanceTag for a while, but I'm still too new to ruby and rails to really grasp what's going in there yet :). I think I kept mistaking the methods without parens as attributes/properties.