# Rails how to programatically get html id from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a Rails form like the following

```
 <% form_for @model do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :column %>
   <%= f.check_box :column %>
 <% end %>
```

Is there a way I can get the html id that will be generated for the 'column' check box? What would be great is if there was a way to add in

```
  <%= f.observe_field :column, options %>
```

Anyone know how to add this to FormBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

For generating an element's id programatically, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017927/generating-the-input-id-with-an-activerecord-model). As it seems, there is no easy way out.

You could add this to FormBuilder by wrapping up certain field tags. See for example [this](http://ramblingsonrails.com/how-to-make-a-custom-form-builder-in-rails).