# How do you get the Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element for reference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

When using the `form_for` helper and a `text_field` call, Ruby on Rails will generate a unique id for the `<input />` element that it outputs. How can I generate the same id for later inclusion into JavaScript generated later?

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
<% end %>
```

Then later in the page:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $('<%= id of the :username field %>').doSomethingReallyCool();
<% end %>
```

Comment: I would like to point out that the additional example in the bounty is just another particular case where the answer will be useful. It's not a different question. To be acceptable the answer should be enough general purpose to fit both the original example and mine. Both examples shows a case where it's necessary to “get the Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element for reference in JavaScript”.

Comment: Meta question about the current bounty https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351561/73226

Comment: @ClaudioFloreani No, that's not OK. Keep in mind that the text of your bounty is no longer visible after the bounty is expires or is awarded. An answer which addresses the question in your bounty will make very little sense after the bounty is gone. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @duskwuff I think you're making comments without understanding that both examples are two special cases of the same general case. The author gives just ONE example of “Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element” and I'm giving another example. Example A and Example B. But the question is “How do you get the Ruby on Rails generated id of a form element for reference in JavaScript?” and it's still lacking a decent answer. Currently accepted answer (“creating a custom form builder”) is considered bad practice nowadays.

Comment: Isn't the id name-of-model_name-of-the-attribute? And can't you not give it an id my specifying it in the html options?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom form builder to expose the property directly

```
class FormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def id_for(method, options={})
   InstanceTag.new( object_name, method, self, object ) \
               .id_for( options )               
  end
end

class InstanceTag < ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag
  def id_for( options )
    add_default_name_and_id(options)
    options['id']
  end
end
```

Then set the default form builder

```
ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = FormBuilder
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Where is the best place to put this in a Rails app?

Comment: Mike: a config/initializers/{file_name}.rb file would do the trick

Comment: I'm having trouble conceptualizing how this is called. Too meta for my brain, I s'pose. Could you provide a simple example?

Comment: In Rails 5, `ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag` should be replaced with `ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Base` and `InstanceTag.new(object_name, method, self, object)` should be `InstanceTag.new(object_name, method, self, options)` instead.

Answer (score 15):

Look at the form builder options:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% form_css_id = "#" + f.options[:html][:id] %>
<% end %>
```

Options should at least include the following data: css class, id, http method and authenticity token.

Comment: f.options[:html] is nil for me.

Comment: It isn't nil for me! I wish I could upvote this more. This is especially useful with HTML5's new "form" attribute. Try this: `<% f.submit "Save Changes", form: f.options[:html][:id] %>`. Now you can use javascript to move that form anywhere you want, and it will still work to submit the form. So nice!

Comment: It appears to be nil for nested objects, but on the parent form it works fine.

Comment: To be clear, the OP asked how to get the id of the username field, not the form id. This returns the form id.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone has a FormBuilder object from a `fields_for` block, it is possible to get its `id` using this snippet:

```
<%= form.fields_for :something do |fields_form| %>
  <%= fields_form.object_name.gsub(/[\[\]]+/, '_').chop %>id
<% end %>
```

`FieldsForm#object_name` returns the field's ID as something like this: `user[address][0]`. Next, the regex substitution changes groups of one or more brackets to underscores. This substitution leaves a trailing underscore, to which it appends the letters `id`. For the example provided before, this results in `user_address_0_id`.

Comment: I am trying the snippet you added.
Is it perhaps?
`<%=  fields_form.object_name.gsub(/[\[\]]+/, '_').chop %>_id`

Answer (score 6):

At least in Rails 7 there is a method called `field_id(user, :password)` which returns `user_password` which is the id the input has.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer, if you're using Rails 7.

Comment: Can confirm, works like a charm in Rails 7

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4.1 I was able to get the id with this:

```
ActionView::Base::Tags::Base.new(
  f.object_name,
  :username,
  :this_param_is_ignored,
).send(:tag_id)
```

It works with nested forms (`fields_for`).

Comment: Works like a charm in Rails 6.1.*, thanks!

Comment: And breaks in Rails 7...  using something internal like this is probably not a good idea

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to specify the id yourself. Here generating the id from the object_id of the form guarantees that it won't conflict with another text_field for username in the case of nested forms.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%- id = "username_#{f.object_id}" %>
  <%= f.text_field :username, :id=>id %>
<% end %>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $("##{id}").doSomethingReallyCool();
<% end %>
```

Comment: This isn't really an option in this case as the JavaScript and form fields are dynamic and I won't necessarily have the ability to control the `f.text_field` call.

Comment: That's an obvious answer to a particular case where the id are not dynamically generated by the Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Javascript code is placed in a ruby embedded file (.erb) that is being interpreted by the server before being sent to the client browser, you can generated the required JS variable with a ruby snippet like:

```
var id='#id_for_'+<%= @user.username %>
var id='#comment_info_'+<%= n %>
```

and then use it simply as `$(id).doSomethingReallyCool();`.

If you need to control the value of the id generated by the form in first instance, you can do it passing the id in the html hash options:

```
f.text_field :username, id:"id_for_#{…}"
```

If you're using a unobtrusive JS approach, you would like to place the JS code into a partial (.js.erb) and have the controller use it if the user client allows JS. E.g.:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

def foo_doo
  … # some logic
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # this will render javascript in file “foo_doo.js.erb” if allowed
    format.html { … } # html fallback for unobtrusive javascript
  end
end
```

This is the recommended approach nowadays. The problem now is that you need to pass the variables to your JS code. If these variables came from a form, place them in opportune hidden form fields. And then use the render's `locals` option to have them available by your partial, as in:

```
format.js { render 'foo_doo', locals: {n:n} }
```

If the JS code is updating a template that use some variables, use the same approach:

```
var id='#comment_info_'+<%= n %>
$(id).replaceWith("<%= j (render partial:…, locals: {…}) %>")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like my own solution that much, but I tried not to go and patch InstanceTag.

Unfortunately that meant lifting the sanitization code from `ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTagMethods`

```
class MyCoolFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    def sanitized_object_name
      @sanitized_object_name ||= object_name.gsub(/\]\[|[^-a-zA-Z0-9:.]/, "_").sub(/_$/, "")
    end

    def field_id_for(method)
      "#{sanitized_object_name}_#{method.to_s.sub(/\?$/,"")}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there are multiple `form_for` in the page and each has it's own submit button. I think this is how I would do this:

Have a hidden field in the the form_for and set it's value to the id of the input field. Here I've chosen `input_#{n}` as the id of the input field. Of course I'll define the id for each input.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username, id: "input_#{n}" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'user[input_id]', value: "input_#{n}" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then on submit I can get the id the form input in my params `params[:user][:input_id]` which I can pass to the `js.erb` using the `locals`.

Hope this helps :)